# What is this PS3 System Software Update Disc? How it was made available? Are there more like this?

Tags: ps3, physical-media, hardware-identification

While browsing Reddit, [I found this picture](https://www.reddit.com/r/ps3hacks/comments/jcwb58/ive_found_this_cd_in_cechg04_box_recently_is_this/?sort=top) of an European CD meant to update the System Software of a PS3 to 2.00.

[image]
[image]

- What is this disc used for? (I ask because it seems pointless, as the CECHGXX console that it came with has System Software 2.30 preinstalled)
- How it was made available? (I feel that it might have been available in some other form like via mail)
- Are there more discs like this? (either the same disc for other regions or more discs with recent software versions)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was only two versions of this disc, both with System Software 2.0: the US & Canada edition (white, in English and French) and the European edition (black, languages change depending of the region). They were only made available with the consoles themselves, as some CECHG Fat consoles came with 1.90 or 1.97 preinstalled instead of 2.30.

The disc for the United States and Canada:

[image]

The disc for Europe:

[image]